# Is it legal to use a person's name for a commercial purpose if it is a household name?

Tags: united-states, trademark, right-of-publicity

As an example, could I make a company called "Einstein Electronics" or "Houdini Locks" (probably not a great name for a lock company) or something without getting permission from the named persons, since they're so well-known?

One real-world example I can think of is Tesla Motors. Did they have to get permission from the Tesla family or anything?

Comment: As long as the name is not under trademark protection for the product or service in question (or, if the trademark is very famous, for *any* product or service), you can use the name.

Comment: @phoog I gave you an up-tick. However, there is always the threat. What this article does not say is that McDonalds ceased all actions when Lord MacDonald, who has a family restaurant for some 700 years, threatened to sue McDonalds for the use of his name. http://articles.chicagotribune.com/1997-02-02/news/9702020275_1_ronald-mcdonald-mcdonald-s-restaurants-scot I though you might like the humor in the story. Being a Scot myself, I see my name used by non-Scots all over the place. Cheers!!

Comment: Are we talking strictly about Federal law? Because California (and many other states) have laws about this.